# how to create deployment pipeline using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration, pipeline, continuous-deployment

What does it mean by deploying code from dev to prod environments using Jenkins. Can anyone please help. I currently have the source code in my gitlab. I need to deploy this code from dev env to prod env

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Source code present in GitLab is just the files that is needed to create a WAR/EAR/JAR to run the application.

It's the environment files if present which makes the application behave slightly different on each environment i.e. **DEV/PROD** the data that you see on **DEV** will not be the same that you see on **PROD**(application is live), as developers tend to test/modify code/data to ensure that the application works as excepted. This is fine on **DEV** but is a big no-no on **PROD** as it will impact business.

Deploying code from dev to prod environments just means building the application with the right environment files e.g **DEV** points to xyz DB but prod points to abc DB.

All this can be achieved with jenkins and if your project uses maven/gradle then with a single line command you can achieve the above.(A bit of googling will help you here)

If your project doesn't involve Maven/Gradle then you will have to replace the environment file each time a build happens based on a parameter which can be passed from jenkins.

Comment: My question is how to copy source code to container using a jenkins job. I have an idea of using docker cp for copying files onto container but that is not working. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: What is the issue there ?? have you tried scp  command?? or using ssh to copy ?? Can you add more info

Comment: I tried docker cp as jenkins is a container and I wanted to copy the code to another container.

Comment: I tried docker cp from jenkins container to another container. For this I installed docker inside docker. (error setting ulimit: operation not permitted)

Answer (score 0):

This whole process is part of DevOps culture. In simple terms it looks like this:

1. Developer pushes changes to source control (i.e. gitlab).
2. Build server (i.e. Jenkins) automatically downloads latest changes and builds an application (i.e. creates setup files or just the binaries). Usually you run tests (unit, integration, automation tests etc.). If something fails then developers get notified about it. This whole process is called continuous integration.
3. If everything went right then you can deploy your application to production. This part of the process is called continuous deployment.

It's a common strategy for web apps. For larger projects QA team tests the software and the software gets deployed once QA team approves it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a python application in my github which does not have any tests. My job is to deploy it into dev, qa and prod env. The question is do I need to build it first inorder to deploy it. I know maven is used to build java applications. How can I build a python application?

Comment: I believe you can create packages for python with tools like cx_Freeze or py2exe. They create msi / exe file that you can copy to your qa/dev/prod environment and install in silent mode (without user interaction).

Comment: I do not need to build the python code. I need to just deploy the source code to another container using jenkins job. Can you please help

Comment: You are asking different question then. I'm not familiar with containers, so can't help you with that. I believe you should create a thread with the question you have asked me in your last comment.